# Hibernate not creating table in MySQL (IntelliJ/SpringBoot/Maven)

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, maven

I have no clue why my Hibernate ORM is not automatically creating a table.. I have successfully established a MySQL connection.

These are the dependencies:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.5</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.authenticatie</groupId>
    <artifactId>authenticatie</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>authenticatie</name>
    <description>Backend authenticatie</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>19</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>18</source>
                    <target>18</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
```

This is the Entity:

```
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.*;

@Entity
public class Postzegel {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;
    private int prijs;
    //    private Image;
    public Postzegel() {
    }

    public Postzegel(int Id, int Prijs) {
        this.id = Id;
        this.prijs = Prijs;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public int getPrijs() {
        return prijs;
    }

    public void setPrijs(int prijs) {
        this.prijs = prijs;
    }
}
```

This is the application properties:

```
#configuration
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3307/pakketjesauthenticatiedb
spring.datasource.username=pakketjesauthenticatiedb
spring.datasource.password=password
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
```

I don't really know witch information I have to provide to be able to find a solution, I will add a photo showing the successful connection with the database.

[image]

Comment: ddl-auto update? why? maybe check create-only. You can check other options

Comment: Unfortunately that does not work

Comment: maybe stupid question but do you have annotation which point to entities packae? @EntityScan if yes add spring.jpa.generate-ddl=true spring.jpa.show-sql=true
logging.level.org.hibernate.SQL=DEBUG to see what is wrong

Comment: (current) main problem: package structure! (your main/springbootApp class doesn't see the entities/repos/controllers) ... [doc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/using.html#using.structuring-your-code) ... simplest solution: move `AuthenticatieApplication` one level (package) up! (like in chap. 2.2 ;)

Comment: I will work on both of your replys in a minute guys, i appreciate y'all !